# Writing script for mac (scp alias with default params)

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, script, scp

I have got to write this lines often:

```
# from project1 dir
scp app/models/user.rb root@mydomain.com:/var/www/project1/app/models
# from project2 dir
scp app/views/posts/index.html.erb root@mydomain.com:/var/www/project2/app/views/posts
scp -r app/mailers root@mydomain.com:/var/www/project2/app/
```

so I want to wrap it as a script

```
scpd project1 app/models/user.rb
scpd project2 app/views/posts/index.html.erb
scpd project2 -r app/mailers
```

so `scpd` will pass all options to scp and take first argument as a dirname on server's `/var/www/` path.

So the question is: **what is a common way for writing terminal scripts on macos?** And some links to read about it. Bash? And maybe I can write it on Ruby? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of these work. Bash, ruby, python, perl, they all come with the system. Do it any way you know how.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that OS X bundles specific versions of those, not always the newest ones (especially Ruby in 1.8.7, Python up to 2.6, etc.)

Comment: Is there is guideline for writing such scripts? And how to define my own named script (such as `scpd`)?

Comment: @fl00r Just write the scripts. From your question I figured you know how to do that. Otherwise I'd recommend you to read the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) first.

Comment: @fl00r I also assumed you were already familiar with the technologies you mentioned. Sorry about that. But any guide and tutorial that works with the versions of these environments you have should work for you, except a few system-specific exceptions (e.g. bash scripts calling linux-specific programs)

Comment: @Daniel Beck, I can write on Python/Ruby/Php/C# but I thought unix way is to use bash here :) so I wanted to see some guides for my first steps

Comment: @fl00r C# is probably not a good idea (need Mono for that), but otherwise, they all are very valid options. If you start a file with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env python` doesn't really matter then ;)

Comment: @Daniel Beck :) I understand about C#/Mono and I really won't use it anyway for scripting

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash function for you:

```
scpd () {
    # the first argument is the project
    # the last argument is the file/dir to send
    # any arguments in the middle are scp options

    args=( "$@" )

    proj="${args[0]}"
    file="${args[@]: -1}"
    scp_args=( "${args[@]): 1: $(( ${#args[@]} - 2 ))}" )
    remote_dir="${file%/*}"

    scp "${scp_args[@]}" "$file" "root@mydomain.com:/var/www/$proj/$remote_dir"
}
```

You can paste it into your ~/.bashrc